# js function not found error

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I feel its strange error !

I am developing WordPress widget for [My site](http://www.greatkosherweddings.com/).In my widget i have the Highslide Popup
form.While submitting form i want to call the particular function.the function is included in header,But it says function is not found.

My form

```
<form  method="post" name="contact_vendor_contact_frm"  
onsubmit="return contact_vendor_contact_frm(this);">
    .....
    </form>
```

**contact_vendor_contact_frm** functions included in header **contact_vendor.js**.You 
can see this in page source

Working place [Here](http://www.diigo.com/item/image/19c1l/6nhk).[My page](http://www.greatkosherweddings.com/)

Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code name attribute of form is equal to function name and it overwrite your function. If you write:

```
console.log(contact_vendor_contact_frm); // this would be point to form element not to your function
```

Answer (score 0):

User Firebug and check if this returns **function**

```
  typeof contact_vendor_contact_frm;
```

If not, then check what the returned value is, to solve the problem.

Comment: In that case, can you show us more code? The page you sent is not opened. Can you show us how and where did you define your function?